# Función para unir los elementos de una arreglo por coma y reemplazar la ultima por una "Y"

Tags: php, php7, php5, php-5.6

Simplemente no entiendo muy bien **cómo es que funciona** el contenido de esta pequeña función:

```
/**
 * Une elementos de un array en un string separados por
 * comas y reemplazar la ultima coma por una "Y"
 *
 * @param array $items contiene todos los elementos
 * @return string
 */
function itemsByComma( $items ) 
{
    $itemsByComma = strtoupper( implode(', ', $items) );
    $setItems = substr_replace( $itemsByComma, " y ", strrpos($itemsByComma, ","), 2 );

    return $setItems;
}
```

Investigué acerca de [strrpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strrpos.php) y es sencillamente claro, pero [substr_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr-replace.php) con tantos argumentos me confunde un poco.

> *Código extraído de un [foro](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/reemplazar-ultima-coma-por-1098391/#post4595658)*
> *El titulo es con intensión de generar SEO en google*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es tan difícil de entender si lees los enlaces que tú mismo proporcionaste y prestas atención a los parámetros proporcionados:

```
substr_replace(
    mixed $string,       // Cadena a modificar
    mixed $replacement,  // Reemplazo de caracteres
    mixed $start,        // Comenzar en una posición específica
    mixed $length        // Total de caracteres a reemplazar
)
```

Ahora, la función str**r**pos(), busca de forma inversa, esa segunda **r** significa "reverse", entonces, comienza a buscar desde el final de la cadena.

Para explicar, modificamos un poco, obteniendo por separado la posición del reemplazo:

```
// Unir todos los elementos del arreglo insertando ", " entre ellos
$itemsByComma = strtoupper( implode(', ', $items) );

// Buscar la primera coma desde el final, es decir, la última en la cadena:
$inicio = strrpos($itemsByComma, ",");

// Reemplazar
$setItems = substr_replace(
    $itemsByComma,  // Cadena donde se aplicará el reemplazo
    " y ",          // Caracteres que van a reemplazar a los originales
    $inicio,        // Comenzar donde se encontró la última coma
    2               // Dos caracteres, coma y espacio
);
```

Comment: ¡Perfecto!, Punto clave de la respuesta **esa segunda r significa "reverse"**